# Something is breaking my package deployment

Tags: python, setuptools, pygments

I use setuptools and a requirements file to satisfy dependencies for my open source module.

Example `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from pip.req import parse_requirements


# parse_requirements() returns generator of
# pip.req.InstallRequirement objects
install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt',
                                  session=False)

# reqs is a list of requirement
reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in install_reqs]

setup(
    name='python-symphony',
    version='0.1.5',
    description='python module for symphony chat',
    author='Matt Joyce',
    author_email='matt@joyce.nyc',
    url='https://github.com/symphonyoss/python-symphony',
    license='Apache 2.0',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    ],
    keywords='symphony chat api python module',
    # install dependencies from requirements.txt
    install_requires=reqs,
    packages=find_packages(),
    # bin files / python standalone executable scripts
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

This has worked for some time.  However, recently my builds have been breaking.  I believe there is a bug in setuptools, possibly related to pygments.

There are two (thus far) identified failure states:

1. It results in the package being installed as a binary wheel (despite no such package existing in PyPI).
2. It results in the package installing in site-packages seemingly correctly, but none of the subclasses can be called from the module.

I can get it to work manually by removing the package from site packages and running:

```
pip install --isolated --no-cache-dir python-symphony
```

but this results in pygments getting messed up somehow.  (I noticed this when trying to debug the module in bpython).

Trying to run this stuff from a venv (wrapped with a Bash script) tends to still fail.

Is anyone aware of a new / recent issue in setuptools that could be responsible for this sort of breakage?

setuptools version: setuptools-33.1.1.dist-info and newer

Ref:
github: https://github.com/symphonyoss/python-symphony
pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-symphony/

Comment: Installing & importing the package seems to work fine for me under Python 2.7.12, setuptools 35.0.2.  Installation also works under Python 3.5.2, setuptools 35.0.2, but then imports fail because lines like "`from base import Base`" are interpreted as absolute imports in Python 3; you need to write them as "`from .base import Base`" instead.  I'm not clear on what problem #1 is supposed to be about; I'm pretty sure that if a PyPI package only has an sdist, pip will use the sdist to build a wheel and then install that.

Comment: thought i had gotten all of those... odd that they aren't coming up in unit tests.  will take a look.